# Comparing a list of keywords to a free text column in a dataframe and retrieving matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, lambda

I am trying to scan a free text column of a pandas dataframe for keywords defined in a list and retrieve the columns in the dataframe that match my list, while also appending the matchedkeyword as a new column to the dataframe .

List of keywords i am attempting to scan for

keywordlist = ['4runner', 'runner', 'avalon', 'avanza', 'camry']

My Dataframe has two columns, an ID column and a free text column like such.

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | i own a toyota camry |
| 1233 | i love my saab |

I am attempting to use the following code to scan the free text portion of my dataframe for the keywords in my list and to append the keyword as a label to the dataframe if there is a match.

Desired output:

| id | text | Match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | i own a toyota camry | camry |
| 1233 | i love my saab | NaN. |

Code:

```
def matches(x):
    for i in keywordlist:
        if x.str.contains(i) is True:
            x.append(i)
        else:
            return None

x=posts['text']
posts['Match'] = posts.apply(lambda x: matches(x), axis = 1)
```

Comment: `posts["Match"] = posts["text"].apply(lambda x: matches(x))`, and instead of `x.append(i)` return `i`. If you want multiple matches than return a list or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

A simple one-liner using `str.extract` would be,

```
posts['match'] = posts.text.str.extract('(' + '|'.join(keywordlist) + ')')
```

Output

```
     id                  text  match
0  1234  i own a toyota camry  camry
1  1233        i love my saab    NaN
```